# Android Can Not Install APK On Phone,SDK Target Issue

Tags: android

I have developed an Android application with a manifest like this

```
<uses-sdk
     android:minSdkVersion="8"
     android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

While using Eclipse I test it Via emulator with `API Level  2.2` and it works fine. Whenever I try to install  the apk via file manager on to my phone, I get the error `X Application Not Installed`. The Android Version of my phone is `4.1.2`.  So kindly guide me is it problem with Target or might be Some Issue With Mobile

Comment: does your phone have empty space? enough for the app?

Comment: what is your mobile name? change the target version based on your mobile.. latest version is 20... also double check whether you installed the app already

Comment: can you paste a log or a screenshot?

Comment: how you get apk ? may be you get it by wrong way , any way after build its in bin folder

Comment: also make sure you enable unknown resource , refer to http://gs4.wonderhowto.com/forum/enable-unknown-sources-android-install-apps-outside-play-store-0150603/

Comment: Is your phone **older than 2.2**?

Comment: last thing delete android:targetSdkVersion="15" just android:minSdkVersion="8"

Comment: well, i used eclipse build tool to unassigned apk , secondly there  is enough space

Comment: change min sdk version 9. It ll work fine

Comment: Any special permission to use sensors?

Comment: Do turn on USB Debugging mode enabled in your device which you try to install

Comment: i am not sure about the generate unsigned app, just hit Run when emulator starts and your app running ok, go to: Proj_Dir/bin you will find the APK there, upload to mobile and install

Comment: My Phone is Using 4.1.2 , Certainly older than 2.2 .I installed it first time , enabled enable unknown resource too

Comment: @tato.rodrigo what kind of sensors? we need to add permissions if you want to access any hardware related.. ex. to access camera

Comment: @Naufal I was wrong. I thought the system would abort the installation for a `<uses-permission />` to a hardware that does not exists on target device. This is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you phone is 4.1.2 (api 16), you can't install your app on your phone because you have declared in your manifest that targetSdkVersion="15"(android 4.0).

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16"(or higher) />
```

Comment: So, if  Update android:targetSdkVersion="16" do like that , Should it Work? Can I Update My Target Version , Thanks Advance